# Post value to PHP using $.post() and return with $.getJSON

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to use $.getJSON inside $.post function and display returned value in textbox (id=desc).
Here is my code:

```
function dataload(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id'); 
    var e = document.getElementById(""+currentId);
    var sel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text; 
    $("#"+currentId).change(function (){
        $.post("test.php", {data:sel}, function(data){
            $.getJSON("test.php", function(data){
                $("#desc").val(data[0].description);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

test.php:

```
<?php
   include('config.php');//db connection
   $itemvalue=($_POST["data"]);
   $item = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM invoice WHERE item='$itemvalue'");
   $data = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($item, true)) {
        $data[] = $row;
   }
   $data = json_encode($data);
   echo $data;
?>
```

but test.php is not taking posted value. So how to post sel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `test.php` twice, once using `$.post` and once using `$.getJSON`. On the first call, the POST param should be passed correctly to your PHP - but you don't do anything with the result of the request. On the second call, you don't transmit any POST param and `$itemvalue` just is empty.

Just use:

```
$.getJSON("test.php", {data:sel}, function(data){
    // [...]
```

and in your PHP:

```
$itemvalue=$_GET["data"]; // $.getJSON performs a GET request
```

btw: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: damn, that's just what I was writing. I always prefer to just use [ajax base object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so I can easily see what's going on or change it later.