# How I can POST a Button value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form in which i use multiple Checkbox. On Checkboxes i use JavaScript for validation If I  checked all checkbox, it proceeds ahead otherwise it show an alert message.
 My code is working Well

**Problem**
Because i have Two Button on my form and they have different functionality. I want to post value of Button on my action page

My Code goes here

```
<script>
function letter_submit(){
  var pr = document.getElementsByName('pr'),
      i = 0;
  var allAreChecked = true;
  for( ; i < pr.length; i++ )
  {
    if( pr[i].checked=='' ) {
      allAreChecked = false;
    }
  }
  if (!allAreChecked) {
    alert("Please Check All Checkboxes");
    exit;
  } else {
    alert("All OK");
    document.getElementById("approve_letter").submit();

  }
}
    </script>

 <form action="letter_approve_action.php" id="approve_letter" name = "approve_letter" method="POST" >

<input type="checkbox" name="pr" id="pr" value="" /> NL is appropriately addressed.
 </br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="pr" id="pr" value="" /> Checked Press Release 
 </br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="pr" id="pr" value="" /> Applicable Methodology is rightly Marked
 </br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="pr" id="pr" value="" /> Respective Sector Study on Website is Updated Within Last 12 Months.
 </br>

<button type="button" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" value="Approve" onclick="letter_submit();">Approve</button>

<button type="button" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" value="Re - Submit" />Re-Submit</button>

</form>
```

On action page i use

```
echo $submit = $_POST ['btn_submit'];
```

and i got an error

```
Notice: Undefined index: btn_submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work_Que_Backup\login\pacra-all\w_q\nl\letter_approve_action.php on line 26
```

Comment: `id` should be unique in same document.

Comment: `$_POST ['btn_submit'];` should be `$_POST['btn_submit'];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post value to PHP using $.post() and return with $.getJSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080921/post-value-to-php-using-post-and-return-with-getjson)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `<button>` tag.

For example:

```
<form method="post">
     <input type="text" name="myText" value="some text here..."/>
     <button type="submit" name="myButton" value="buttonValue">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The label tht is displayed is "Submit" but you can access your button value from the server with a different value.

It will be accessible with **php** on server side as:

```
echo $_POST['myButton']; //buttonValue
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that your button is of type "button", and you trigger the POST by javascript - so the value for btn_submit is never set.

Change the button type to "submit" and move the event handler `onclick=...` to the form tag `onsubmit=...`. In your javascript function, you can the cancel the submit by returning `false`.